# P4Sandbox files are readonly even with setting allwrite

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to configure P4Sandbox so that I can follow a workflow similar to git.  However, after setting up the sandbox the files in my new repo are still readonly.  I've tried using `p4 client` and `p4v` to change the settings to `allwrite`.  It looks like that change is successful, but after making it the files in the directory are still readonly.  Is changing from `noallwrite` to `allwrite` supposed to change the permissions on all files managed by the repository?  If so any ideas on what I might be doing wrong.

(Note that I am using Windows 7 x64).

Comment: After you change your client spec, try running 'p4 sync //...#0' followed by 'p4 sync', and see if the local file permissions change.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up turning off read-only using attrib.  After that it looked like P4Sandbox was working, but I had other problems with syncing with the main repository.  I might experiment with it more later, but for now I'm sticking with the regular Perforce workflow.