# P4V allwrite option changes back to default after re-opening

Tags: perforce, p4v

I'm using P4 client

(*Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2014.3/1007540, OS: Win8.1*),

**and wand the "Allwrite" option in my workspace to be always on** (enables me to edit files without checking them out before).

After I check that option in my workspace

(*Connection->Edit Current Workspace...->Advanced->File Options->[checkbox]Allwrite* ),

it works as expected, and my files stay writeable.

Problem is, **after I close P4V, the "Allwrite" flag returns to it's default value** (which is: unchecked).

Any idea how to do that?
(Maybe passing it as a parameter on P4V launch, P4 console or whatever?)

I searched the web (this is the only question on the subject I've found, but it doesn't cover mine: [p4sandbox-files-are-readonly-even-with-setting-allwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935286/p4sandbox-files-are-readonly-even-with-setting-allwrite)), and didn't find any solutions...

[set the allwrite option](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Displaying_client_specifications.html)

P.S.

Please spare the: "you shouldn't use P4 that way", and the: "you're probably a git user. in P4 we do things differently". For the ones of you that can't stop of asking me that, lets say my question is only a theoretically one.

Comment: Hi Cap'n. I'm using the same version as you. I don't see this behavior. What happens if you display the workspace via the command line ('p4 client')?

Comment: @tkosinski: din't know about the 'p4 client' command. thnx!. but still, it doesn't work. iv'e edited the client spec file (the file that `p4 client My_Worksspace_Name` command has opened), and changed the flag i want (noallwrite -> allwrite), but when i save and close the file i'm getting this output:  `Client My_Worksspace_Name not changed.` (and of course the spec file didn't change. do you have any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's sure a head-scratcher. Do you have the spec depot enabled? If so, you should be able to view the client and any history (and any changes to it). Or view the client from another workstation? I would guess this would be an interesting question for Perforce Support.

Comment: @tkosinski: i'll try your advice about the spec depot

Comment: Have you talked with your Perforce administrator? This could be due to a trigger that the administrator has installed on your server.

Comment: @BryanPendleton: might. i'll check